# Is there a program that allows me to test for multiple browser sizes?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, cross-platform

I'm on a mac and I'm looking to test multiple sizes for multiple browsers.  I also use parallels to run windows and IE as well, so if there is any site / program that is cross platform that would be great to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a program, but service:

http://browsershots.org/

It has different operating systems and browser versions and you have options to define sizes, java/flash settings etc.

Comment: Thank you, I've used this program before, its pretty good, but super slow.

Answer (score 0):

IE DEveloper toolbar for IE at least! [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359)

Comment: Also the firefox web dev plugin is great for mac